# Without trigonometric functions, I want to find $f$ which is differentiable at $x_0$ but $f'$ is not continuous at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Without using the fuctions $\cos$ and $\sin$, I want to find a function $f$ which is differentiable at a point $x_0$ but $f'$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

I used this function which is differentiable at $0$ but $f'$ is not continuous at $0$:
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})& \text{si } x\neq 0\\
\\
0 & \text{si } x=0.
\end{array}\right.$$

But I like to construct a function without $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the general spirit of this counterexample, we want a function that (1) has $f'(x)$ diverge by oscillation as $x\to0$ but (2) has $f'(0)=\frac{f(0+x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ converge to $0$ (assuming we have set $f(0)=0$).

Comment: Why not integrate the function you want for $f'$ - choose a simple one.

Comment: Here is an interesting example. $f(x)=x^2\arctan(\tan \frac1x)$ has $f'(x)=2x\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-1$ *converge* to $-1$ as $x\to0$ but not to $f'(0)=0$ so it is discontinuous. The general tactic of setting $f(x)=x^2\cdot g(1/x)$ for an oscillating $g(x)$ is fruitful, but note that setting $g(x)$ to be a square wave (i.e. the sign of arctan in the previous example) does not work since $f'$ is continuous, so it seems that some local continuity in $g$ may be required.

Comment: @Jam Thanks but I teach L1 economic and they don't know trigonometric functions. I hope to contruct a function with usual functions like $\ln$, $e^x$, $\sqrt{x}$..

Comment: @Student It makes absolutely no sense to introduce continuity and derivatives before basic trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Jam This is the official program from the ministery. So I must not teach trigonometric functions

Comment: *I teach L1 economic and they don't know trigonometric functions* --- Given this, I strongly recommend that you dispense with trying to write an explicit formula and simply draw a graph (draw the oscillations; no one needs to know about trig functions to understand what they're seeing) and include appropriate constraints to obtain what you want. For example: For diff., the graph squeezes down fast enough to a point as you approach the origin (and explicitly include $(0,0)$ in the graph); also have the max/min separation rate of decrease so that secant slopes with the origin become unbounded.

Comment: Yes but I hope to construct a function. I try to find $f$ such that $f'(x)=(1+lnx) e^x$ when $x$ psoitive and $0$ if $x$ is negative. Here $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: but I cannot calculate the primitive of $e^x/x$

Comment: *so that secant slopes with the origin become unbounded* --- This should be "so that the derivative is unbounded in every neighborhood of the origin". *Yes but I hope to construct a function.* --- I think you're wasting your time and your students' time with this. If you cannot assume trigonometry, then what you're trying to do is WAY outside the scope of what you should be teaching. And if for some reason it's not, then you're conveying wrong ideas to students by insisting that functions must be explicitly given in some way (unless this is some kind of computer programming situation).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I think there exist some known examples.

Comment: @Student You should include the information that your audience doesn't know trigonometric functions into your question.

Comment: *I think there exist some known examples* --- I'm pretty sure the answer is NO under any reasonable interpretation of your constraints. And to restate my previous concerns, why would students who are not expected to have knowledge of trigonometry being exposed to this type of counterexample, and why do explicit formulas have to be used instead of focusing on the CONCEPTS with an appropriately drawn schematic diagram (like a Venn diagram for certain combinatorial problems)? Indeed, the latter seems to reinforce the common beginning student's belief that functions have to be given by formulas.

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment)
It may be not the most exciting example but my first thought was to build $\sin$-ish function. Namely let $\phi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|\phi\|_{C(\mathbb{R})}<\infty$, $\phi(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, $\phi(x)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ and $\phi'$ has no limit at infinity (so let $\phi$ oscillate). Then $f$ defined as $$f(x)=x^2\phi(1/x) \quad \& \quad f(0)=0$$
has the property that we are interested in. Simply $$\frac{h^2\phi(1/h)}{h}\to 0$$
as $h\to 0$ (so $f'$ exist at zero). But since $f'(x)=2x\phi(1/x)-\phi'(1/x)$ except zero and $f'(0)=0$ the function $f'$ is not continous at $0$ which results from the calculations $$\lim_{h\to 0}2h\phi(1/h)-\phi'(1/h) =-\lim_{h\to 0}\phi'(1/h) =\text{don't exist}.$$
Well maybe some technical stuff is missing but this boring example shows more or less whats is the problem. Maybe some assumptions are not necessary, maybe more exciting examples are there but if you find sufficient $\phi$ you may build your own example.

Answer (score -2):

$|x|$ is continuous at 0, but it's derivative is not.

Comment: (-1) The function is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: The derivative has limit -1 at x<0 and 1 at x>0 so it has a jump discontinuity at 0.

Comment: *The derivative has limit -1 at x<0 and 1 at x>0 so it has a jump discontinuity at 0* --- The same can be said for the function $g$ defined as follows: $g(x) = -1$ if $x<0$ and $g(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ (with $g(0)$ not being defined). The function $g$ satisfies what you said in your comment, but the function $g$ is NOT defined at zero. To be an example for the OP, the function's derivative needs to be defined (i.e. exist) at $x=0.$ The absolute value function is probably the most basic type of function one sees in beginning calculus whose derivative does NOT exist somewhere (has a corner point).